# Recognize phrases ending by "?" from a given text in Prolog

Tags: prolog, tokenize, swi-prolog

I'm gonna write a program in Prolog in order to analyze a text and to recognize the questions within it.
Given a text, the program have to recognize all sentences ending by an interrogative mark and save them in a list. Then every element of that list (that is, each phrase ending by "?") will be analyzed and simplified to make sure they will start with the "WH-questions".

Here an example:

"What is climate change?
The planet's climate has constantly been changing over geological time. [...]
What is the "greenhouse effect"?
The greenhouse effect refers to the way the Earth's atmosphere traps some of the energy from the Sun. [...].
The question is: how will these balance out? "

The list should contain: ["What is climate change?","What is the greenhouse effect ?", " how will these balance out?"]

Using split_string/4 I obtain this list

L = ["What is climate change", "The planet's (...). What is the greenhouse effect" , "The greenhouse (...). The question is: how will these balance out?"]

I don't know how to analyze and further to split each elements of the list in order to have the first list I've shown you.

Can you help me, please? Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to feed a DCG with the output of [tokenize_atom](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=tokenize_atom/2):

```
?- tokenize_atom('What is climate change?', L).
L = ['What', is, climate, change, ?].
```

Then you can capture all the content between literals `'What'` and `?`.

To accomplish the capture, [library(dcg/basics)](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc/swi/library/dcg/basics.pl) has string//1 that could help.

Example:

```
:- use_module(library(dcg/basics)).

wh_capture(P, Cs) :-
    tokenize_atom(P, Tks),
    phrase(wh_capture(Cs), Tks).

wh_capture([]) --> [].
wh_capture([C|Cs]) -->
    ['What'], string(Content), [?], {C=['What'|Content]},
    wh_capture(Cs).
wh_capture(Cs) --> string(_), [.], wh_capture(Cs).
```

Usage:

```
?- wh_capture('What about you? Phrase to skip. What now?',L).
L = [['What', about, you], ['What', now]]
```

string//1 has a peculiar behaviour... I usually would place a cut after the end sequence delimiter... like

```
wh_capture([C|Cs]) -->
    ['What'], string(Content), [?], {C=['What'|Content]},
    !, wh_capture(Cs).
```

Comment: I tried to do that also with atomic_list_concat/3 but I don't know how capture all the conten and put them into a separate list. Let's make an example:

tokenize_atom('What is climate change? The planet's climate has constantly been changing over geological time. The question is: how will these balance out?', L).

L = ['What', is, climate, change, ? , The, Planet's, climate, has, constantly, been, changing, over, geological, time, The, question, is:, how, will, these, balance, out, ? ].

I want to copy the phrase between What/Where/How etc. and "?" in a separate list or make an assert.

Comment: That is, 

L1 = [What, is, the, climate, change, ?]
L2 = [How will these balance out?]

Comment: Thank you for the example. I'll study and modify it for may purpose ;)

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is naive for any language (and this is a very deep subject), so don't try to re-invent the wheel (at least until you *know* what to reinvent). Google for a) parsing and then b) [Prolog] Natural Language Processing.

Basically, before further analysis, you need (in the sense to not have a million problems later) to tokenize first.

Comment: What I want is not to re-invent the wheel. I know it's a deep subject. I thought there was some simple way to analyze sentences and split them when the interrogative mark is found. 
For what I have to do, is not important if the question make sense or not, just wanna a sentence from the text.
Anyway, I thank you for your answer and I' ll  follow your advice :)